# How would I create a matrix using strings?

Tags: c#

For example, if I have {[1 0 3; 2 0 3; 3 0 3]}, how would I make it look like

1 0 3

2 0 3

3 0 3

I know I have to use delimters to separate 1 0 3 from 2 0 3. I can use the size of the string as my rows right? If I can get some help that would be fantastic.

Comment: “make it look like” where? In a console window? A WPF app? A web site? How are you displaying your strings now?

Comment: `{[1 0 3; 2 0 3; 3 0 3]}` this is matrix? and this "table" is output that you want?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to output it in a console window. I have to using a string with values inside of them to create a matrix. I know you have to convert the string to an array and then to a matrix, but I'm having trouble with the syntax

Comment: google your steps that are required and you have the solution. This is not a site where you post a question and get ready to use code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print them in a console window then do something like this:

```
string str = "1 0 3; 2 0 3; 3 0 3";
string[] split = str.Split(';');

foreach (string s in split) //OR for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

If those `{}` and `[]` are actually your unwanted characters then just do a `String.Trim` or `String.Remove`

When you do `str.Split(';')`, `1 0 3` is stored in `split[0]`, `2 0 3` in `split[1]`, and so on. And of course, `split[0][0]` would be `1`, `split[0][1]` would be `0`. With that in mind you should know what to do with these arrays.

edit: I guess this is what you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < split[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(split[i][j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. How would I convert this string into an array? I want to use this string to produce an array which I can then use a for loop for(i = 0; i < stringlength; i < ++) which is the row. I can then use another for loop for(j=0; j <   ; j ++ ) which is the column. Any advice?

Comment: After `string.Split`, they become arrays. So instead of `foreach`, you can just write `for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)`

Comment: Can you use another for loop so that the 1 in 1 0 3 is a separate integer? So would it be for (int i = 0; i < str.Length, i ++) 
                       { 
                          for (int j = 0; j < split.Length., j++)
                          {

Comment: Thanks so much. Just one more question.. I know split is 1 0 3, but can you create another split within the 103 to make 1 a separate array? So can I create string[] split = str.Split(' ')? The space will differentiate one array from another.Once again thanks a lot you're a life saver. And is there a way to parse that 1 0 3 to create i to be rows, j to be columns